# Time complexity of scipy's integrate.solve_ivp

Tags: scipy, ode

I use scipy's integrate.solve_ivp function to solve an ODE over a time interval. The method and precision is fixed as 'rtol=1e-5, atol=1e-5, method="RK45"'. But when I change the time interval from [0,1] to [0,0.01], the speed of solving is only twice faster. How can I configurate to make it 100 times faster?

Comment: This depends on how expensive your ODE function is. It could be that the main part of the time you measure is in both cases the overhead of setting up the integration method. Another variant could be that in the initial 0.01 segment the system rapidly changes requiring many small steps, and arrives at some equilibrium state. Then the remaining segment to 1.0 you have only a few large steps. You could test that with a more expensive ODE method, like a method-of-lines discretization of a PDE, or a constantly stiff system like the Vander Pol oscillator or some other chaotic (Duffing) oscillator.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. What I'm trying is the equivalent probability ODE of an SDE for score-based generative model (a new branch of deep learning). The initial segment is indeed more significant than tail, so if the first 0.01 segment takes inevitably large computing overhead, I could not expect to decrease much time cost.